# SQL - company for each column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the below code running in SQL. what i am trying to do is bringing the company for each column (min, max and the latest prices) now the present code reads a company name (i dont know how it decides)

thanks for your help

```
SELECT CLC.DEFINITION_
    ,ITM.CODE
    ,itm.NAME
    ,min(isnull(STL.price, 0)) [min price]
    ,max(isnull(STL.price, 0)) [max]
    ,SUM(total) / SUM(amount) AS [avr]
    --SON SATINALMA FIYATI
    ,ISNULL((
            SELECT TOP 1 PRC.PRICE
            FROM LG_092_01_STLINE AS PRC
            WHERE PRC.STOCKREF = ITM.LOGICALREF
                AND PRC.PRICE > 0
                AND PRC.TRCODE = 1
                AND PRC.CANCELLED = 0
                AND PRC.INVOICEREF > 0
            ORDER BY PRC.DATE_ DESC
            ), 0) AS latestprice
FROM LG_092_ITEMS AS ITM
INNER JOIN LG_092_01_STLINE AS STL ON ITM.LOGICALREF = STL.STOCKREF
INNER JOIN LG_092_CLCARD AS CLC ON CLC.LOGICALREF = STL.CLIENTREF
WHERE STL.PRICE > 0
    AND TRCODE = 1
    AND CANCELLED = 0
    AND INVOICEREF > 0
GROUP BY ITM.LOGICALREF
    ,ITM.CODE
    ,ITM.NAME
    ,STL.STOCKREF
    ,CLC.DEFINITION_
ORDER BY ITM.CODE
```

---

Sample Data I am trying to reach

```
+-------------------+----------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------+
|   Material Code   |       Material Name        |  min price  | cheapest company  | max. price  | expensive company |  avr price  | latestprice | latest purchased company  |
+-------------------+----------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------+
| 150.01.001.01.001 | DEMIR NERVURLU A500C 8 MM  |  26,750.00  | METALLOKOMPLEKT-M |  26,750.00  | METALLOKOMPLEKT-M |  26,750.00  |  28,900.00  | METALLOKOMPLEKT-M         |
| 150.01.001.01.001 | DEMIR NERVURLU A500C 8 MM  |  29,600.00  | PERIGEY           |  29,600.00  | PERIGEY           |  29,600.00  |  28,900.00  | PERIGEY                   |
| 150.01.001.01.001 | DEMIR NERVURLU A500C 8 MM  |  28,900.00  | PERIGEY           |  28,900.00  | PERIGEY           |  28,900.00  |  28,900.00  | PERIGEY                   |
| 150.01.001.01.005 | DEMIR NERVURLU A500C 10 MM |  25,900.00  | METALLOKOMPLEKT-M |  27,500.00  | METALLOKOMPLEKT-M |  26,108.89  |  25,900.00  | METALLOKOMPLEKT-M         |
| 150.01.001.01.005 | DEMIR NERVURLU A500C 10 MM |  27,100.00  | METALLOKOMPLEKT-M |  27,100.00  | METALLOKOMPLEKT-M |  27,100.00  |  25,900.00  | METALLOKOMPLEKT-M         |
| 150.01.001.01.010 | DEMIR NERVURLU A500C 12 MM |  25,700.00  | METALLTORG        |  25,700.00  | METALLTORG        |  25,700.00  |  31,900.00  | METALLTORG                |
| 150.01.001.01.010 | DEMIR NERVURLU A500C 12 MM |  23,850.00  | PERIGEY           |  31,900.00  | PERIGEY           |  26,087.20  |  31,900.00  | PERIGEY                   |
| 150.01.001.01.010 | DEMIR NERVURLU A500C 12 MM |  24,100.00  | METALLTORG        |  25,000.00  | METALLTORG        |  24,698.69  |  31,900.00  | METALLTORG                |
| 150.01.001.01.017 | DEMIR NERVURLU A500C 14 MM |  25,400.00  | METALLTORG        |  25,400.00  | METALLTORG        |  25,400.00  |  25,400.00  | METALLTORG                |
+-------------------+----------------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: love those table names.

Comment: So basically what you want to Know ? how this query working or if it has issue, what is the issue?

Comment: @AbhilashRVankayala this query works normally but i couldnt manage to insert the companies from which i bought the cheapest, the most expensive one and the latest purchase...

Comment: @MitchWheat i wish i could change )))

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ms SQL 2008

Comment: Please include sample data and schema, with current and expected results, ideally as a SQLFiddle.